# What is happening when I right click JBoss Runtime Server with a web project in Eclipse and choose "Clean"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I usually do it when I add projects to Jboss or after changing datasource connection. But I don't know what is happening 'behind the scenes'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It removes your deployed project from the web server. It has nothing to do with JBoss. Have you ever visited the directory where your application is deployed ?? If not, then I will recommend you to visit the directory where actually your web-app is deployed in JBosss. There you will see a folder named as your web-app something like this MyProjectEAR.ear if the project is an ear project with name MyProjectEar. Now I will ask you to click on "Clean". As soon as you do that, you will see that the folder vanishes, and later again appears when you again publish your app.
So to sum up, this action removes your deployed project and helps in re-publishing of your app. This helps in normal functioning if there is a major change in your app and the server fails to hot deploy it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I visited and it's gone. What is the difference between 'Clean' and 'Publish'? 'Publish' seems to do the same.

Comment: Cleans only clean. If your server is running then clicking clean will clean it, but after a few seconds web-app will be published automatically. So you cannot understand the difference b/w publish and clean